# The equivalence of fully nonlinear Yamabe equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

On a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $n \geq 3$, consider the Schouten tensor
$$
A_g=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(\operatorname{Ric}_g-\frac{1}{2(n-1)} R_g g\right),
$$
where $\mathrm{Ric}_g$ denotes the Ricci curvature. Let $\lambda\left(A_g\right)=\left(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n\right)$ denote the eigenvalues of $A_g$ with respect to $g$, and let
$$\text{ (1.1)$\quad$ $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open convex symmetric cone with vertex at the origin,}$$
$$
(1.2)\quad \left\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lambda_i>0,1 \leq i \leq n\right\} \subset \Gamma \subset\left\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i>0\right\},
$$$$\text{(1.3)$\quad$  $f \in C^{\infty}(\Gamma) \cap C^0(\bar{\Gamma})$ be concave, homogeneous of degree one, and symmetric in $\lambda_i$,}$$
$$
(1.4)f>0 \text { in }\, \Gamma, \quad f=0 \text { on } \partial \Gamma ; \quad f_{\lambda_i}>0 \text { in }\, \Gamma\quad  \forall\, 1 \leq i \leq n .
$$The following fully nonlinear version of the Yamabe problem has received much attention in recent years:
$$
(1.5)\quad f\left(\lambda\left(A_{u^{\frac{4}{n-2}} g}\right)\right)=1, \quad u>0 \quad \text { and } \quad \lambda\left(A_{\hat{g}}\right) \in \Gamma \quad \text { on } M .
$$
For $1 \leq k \leq n$, let $\sigma_k(\lambda)=\sum_{1 \leq i_1<\cdots<i_k \leq n} \lambda_{i_1} \cdots \lambda_{i_k}, \lambda=\left(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, denote the $k$-th elementary symmetric function, and let $\Gamma_k$ denote the connected component of $\left\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sigma_k(\lambda)>0\right\}$ containing the positive cone $\left\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n>\right.$ $0\}$. Then $(f, \Gamma)=\left(\sigma_k^{1 / k}, \Gamma_k\right)$ satisfies (1.1)-(1.4). When $(f, \Gamma)=\left(\sigma_1, \Gamma_1\right),(1.5)$ is the Yamabe problem in the so-called positive case.

When $M$ is a Euclidean domain and $g=g_{\text {flat}}$ is the flat metric, equation (1.5) takes the form
$$
f\left(\lambda\left(A^u\right)\right)=1, \quad u>0
$$
where $\lambda\left(A^u\right)$ denotes the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^u$ with entries
$$
\left(A^u\right)_{i j}:=-\frac{2}{n-2} u^{-\frac{n+2}{n-2}} \nabla_{i j} u+\frac{2 n}{(n-2)^2} u^{-\frac{2 n}{n-2}} \nabla_i u \nabla_j u-\frac{2}{(n-2)^{-2}} u^{-\frac{2 n}{n-2}}|\nabla u|^2 \delta_{i j} .
$$
Equation (1.5) is a second order fully nonlinear elliptic equation of $u$.

Another equation which is closely related to (1.6) is
$$
(1.7)\quad \lambda\left(A^u\right) \in \partial \Gamma, \quad u>0
$$
My question is how to prove  that Equation (1.7) is equivalent to
$$
f\left(\lambda\left(A^u\right)\right)=0, \quad u>0 \quad \text { and } \quad \lambda\left(A^u\right) \in \bar{\Gamma} .
$$Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why isn't that trivial from your (1.4)?